# How to use com.gluonhq.ignite-spring?

Tags: graalvm, gluon, graalvm-native-image

I found a video on YouTube **Paul Anderson & Gail Anderson - Front and Center! JavaFX with Spring Boot**. I have cloned their repository `https://github.com/gailasgteach/JavaFX-SpringBoot-Samples`.

I compiled the project, created a jar file using "mvn package" and launched it using "java -jar spring-ignite-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".

I found a dependency in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

So it is possible to create an executable *.exe file (I use Windows).

But I don't understand how to do it. How can I use gluonhq to create an executable *.exe file containing both javafx and spring boot?